# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 went wrong with dependency & exit status 127 errors

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I tried to upgrade my 14.04 ubuntu to 16.04 but I got all sorts of errors similar to this:

[image: error status 127]

[image: dependency error]

Running `dpkg --configure -a` in recovery console results in this error:

[image: dpkg --configure -a]

My system is broken. What can I do to solve this other than re-install everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 from scratch. I think there were too many errors to be able to solve this.